# unable to parse PDF in a right format - PDFminer

Tags: python, pdf

**Screenshot**

[image]

I wanted to extract data from one PDF, i have attached the image of it. I am able to extract text but the row labels and respective co-ordinates are not in sync.

All row headers are coming one after the other followed by values. But i am expected the row header to follow by the respective co-ordinate.
Emetteur :
XYXYXYX 
Garant :
Rang de créance des Titres :
Format :
Devise Prévue :
Montant Nominal Total :
- Tranche :
- Série :
Prix d'Emission :
Valeur(s) Nominale(s)
Date d'Emission : (JJ/MM/AAAA)
Date de Début de Période d’Intérêts :
Date d'Echéance : (JJ/MM/AAAA)
XYXYXYX 
Assortis de Sûretés 
Les Titres sont garantis par XYXYXYX et sécurisés avec recours contre 
l’Emetteur limité au Pool d’Actifs Gagés (voir la section Dispositions relatives 
aux Titres Assortis de Sûretés ci-dessous). 
EUR 
EUR 30 000 000 
EUR 30 000 000 
100% du Montant Nominal Total 
EUR 1 000 
05/07/2017 
Sans objet 
05/07/2029

I am using the below code.

```
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(file, pagenos):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    str = (retstr.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
```

I tried to check if it is a table using Tabula, but its not a table format. Please help.

Comment: Scraping tables from PDFs with the right formatting and only using free tools is _very very difficult_. But in your case, if you always have the same table format, you could try parsing the values that are all stuck together to separate them (e.g.: Tranche and Série are always in Euros, les Dates are always in date format).

Comment: I have only done this in ABBYY FineReader, which is a commercial tool, and even then I had to draw and size the table around the content. I can't tell which package you're using to parse the image, but I'd think you would need to inform it about the table dimensions.